# Как разбить строку tr таблицы в html

Tags: javascript, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таблицу строю динамически по JSON файлу, но вылазит часть строки.
Должно быть так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код

```
window.onload = function(){


    // функция загрузки данных
    function loadData(url, callback){
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.status == 200  && xhr.readyState == 4){
                callback(xhr.responseText);
            } 
        }

        xhr.open('Get', url);
        xhr.send();
    }


    // функция создания шапки таблицы
    function createHeadTable(){
        var thead = document.createElement('thead');

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var thNameCompany = document.createElement('th');
                thNameCompany.innerHTML = "Campaign";
                tr.appendChild(thNameCompany);

            var thDate = document.createElement('th');
                thDate.innerHTML = "Date";
                tr.appendChild(thDate);

            var thClicks = document.createElement('th');
                thClicks.innerHTML = "Clicks";
                tr.appendChild(thClicks);

            var thRegistrations = document.createElement('th');
                thRegistrations.innerHTML = "Registrations";
                tr.appendChild(thRegistrations);

            var thCurrency = document.createElement('th');
                thCurrency.innerHTML = 'Currency';
                tr.appendChild(thCurrency);

            var thFirstDepositsCount = document.createElement('th');
                thFirstDepositsCount.innerHTML = "First Deposits count";
                tr.appendChild(thFirstDepositsCount);

            var thDepositsSum = document.createElement('th');
                thDepositsSum.innerHTML = "Deposits sum";
                tr.appendChild(thDepositsSum);

            var thNGR = document.createElement('th');
                thNGR.innerHTML = "NGR";
                tr.appendChild(thNGR);

            var thPartnersIncome = document.createElement('th');
                thPartnersIncome.innerHTML = "Partner's income";
                tr.appendChild(thPartnersIncome);
        thead.appendChild(tr);


        return thead;
    }


    //функция создает тело таблицы
    function createBodyTable(campaigns){

        let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        // перебираем список компаний
        campaigns.map((item_campaigns)=>{
            console.log(item_campaigns);
            //функция создания строк и ячеек
            createRowsCells(item_campaigns, tbody);
        });

        return tbody;
    }


    //функция создает строки и ячейки
    function createRowsCells(object_compaings, table_body){
        //проходимся по массиву data
        object_compaings.data.map((item_data, index_data)=>{
            //создаем строку
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            //проверяем условие на 1 строку
            if(index_data == 0){
                //создаем ячейку названия компании
                let tdNameComp = document.createElement('td');
                let linkNameCompany = document.createElement('a');
                    linkNameCompany.setAttribute('href', '/partner/campaigns/' + object_compaings.id);
                    linkNameCompany.innerHTML = object_compaings.name;
                    tdNameComp.appendChild(linkNameCompany);
                    tdNameComp.setAttribute('rowspan', object_compaings.data.length);
                    tr.appendChild(tdNameComp);
            }
            //определяем наличие данных currencies
             let lengthCurrencies = item_data.currencies.length;

            //создаем ячейки Date, Clicks, Registrations
            let tdDate = document.createElement('td');
                tdDate.setAttribute('rowspan', lengthCurrencies > 1 ? lengthCurrencies : 1);
                tdDate.innerHTML = item_data.date;
                tr.appendChild(tdDate);

            let tdClicks = document.createElement('td');
                tdClicks.setAttribute('rowspan', lengthCurrencies > 1 ? lengthCurrencies : 1);
                tdClicks.innerHTML = item_data.clicks;
                tr.appendChild(tdClicks);

            let tdRegistration = document.createElement('td');
                tdRegistration.setAttribute('rowspan', lengthCurrencies > 1 ? lengthCurrencies : 1);
                tdRegistration.innerHTML = item_data.registrations;
                tr.appendChild(tdRegistration);

            //проверяем содержит ли currencies данные и выводим остальные данные
            if (lengthCurrencies){
                //проходим по массиву currencies
                item_data.currencies.map((item_currencies, index_currencies)=>{

                    let tdCode = document.createElement('td');
                        tdCode.innerHTML = item_currencies.code;
                        tr.appendChild(tdCode);

                    let tdFirstDepositCount = document.createElement('td');
                        tdFirstDepositCount.innerHTML = item_currencies.first_deposits_count;
                        tr.appendChild(tdFirstDepositCount);

                    let tdDepositsSum = document.createElement('td');
                        tdDepositsSum.innerHTML = item_currencies.deposits_sum;
                        tr.appendChild(tdDepositsSum);

                    let tdNGR = document.createElement('td');
                        tdNGR.innerHTML = item_currencies.ngr;
                        tr.appendChild(tdNGR);

                    let tdPartnersIncome = document.createElement('td');
                        tdPartnersIncome.innerHTML = item_currencies.partner_income;
                        tr.appendChild(tdPartnersIncome);
                    table_body.appendChild(tr);
                });

            } else{
                let tdCode = document.createElement('td');
                    tdCode.innerHTML = "";
                    tr.appendChild(tdCode);

                let tdFirstDepositCount = document.createElement('td');
                    tdFirstDepositCount.innerHTML = "";
                    tr.appendChild(tdFirstDepositCount);

                let tdDepositsSum = document.createElement('td');
                    tdDepositsSum.innerHTML = "";
                    tr.appendChild(tdDepositsSum);

                let tdNGR = document.createElement('td');
                    tdNGR.innerHTML = "";
                    tr.appendChild(tdNGR);

                let tdPartnersIncome = document.createElement('td');
                    tdPartnersIncome.innerHTML = "";
                    tr.appendChild(tdPartnersIncome);
            }



            table_body.appendChild(tr);
        });

    }


    // функция создания таблицы
    function createTable(data){
        console.log(data);
        // создаем div
        let div = document.createElement('div');
            div.setAttribute('class', 'container');
        //создаем заголовок для названия бренда
        let h2 = document.createElement('h2');
            h2.innerHTML = data.name;
        // создаем таблицу
        let table = document.createElement('table');
            // добавляем заголовок к таблице
            table.appendChild(createHeadTable());
            // создаем тело таблицы
            table.appendChild(createBodyTable(data.campaigns));

        //добавляем заголовок и таблицу в div
        div.appendChild(h2);
        div.appendChild(table);

        return div;
    }


    // запуск скрипта
    loadData('http://localhost:3000/', (text)=>{
        let data = JSON.parse(text);
        let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        //console.log(data);
        data.brands.map((item_brands) =>{
            body.appendChild(createTable(item_brands));
        });
    });


}
```

Kак я понимаю, у меня ошибка в функции `createRowsCells`, когда я прохожусь по массиву `currencies`. Как правильно вложить строки?

Comment: руби ее топором!

Comment: по сабжу - мы то откуда знаем по какому файлу и каким образом вы ее там строите, по картинкам отгадаем что ли? ошибку видно, да. но как откуда и почему  она берется никто по скриншотика не скажет.

Comment: если вложенный цикл по валютам идет у вас. то, очевидно, не закрываете `<tr>`. на первой итерации  валют у вас должен быть пропуск `tr`, а на последующих перед выводом `</tr><tr>`, чего у вас нет, вот и получаются все `td` в одну строку.